# I am trying to create a letter Y using ascii art in python 3 and am having trouble finishing the excersise

Tags: python, ascii

```
def Y(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n+1):
            if j == i or j == n-i:
                print('*',end = '')
            print(' ',end = '')
            if j > (n/2)+1 and i>(n/2)+1:
                print(' ', end='')
        print()
```

Right now the code prints out this:

> > > Y(5)
> > >       *     * 
> > >        *   *
> > >         * *
> > >         * *
> > >        *   *
> > >       I cant figure out how to remove the two bottom right "*" to make it a y and not an x

[image: This is what the code is supposed to print out]

Answer (score 0):

You're solution is very close, it just needs one more condition:

```
def Y(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n+1):
            if j == i or j == n-i:
                print('*',end = '')

                # stop printing '*' or ' ' if i > n/2
                if i > n/2:
                    break

            print(' ',end = '')
            if j > (n/2)+1 and i>(n/2)+1:
                print(' ', end='')
        print()
```

it's helpful to draw out each iteration and see how the variables are moving and what is actually being printed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I’d been stuck on this for entirely too long